# Asp.Net: Access is denied error message after changing url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck with a following problem:
built a small application in asp.net, which was reachable under url, let say:

***webservice.domain.com/AppName***

Because the url will be sent in SMS, I had to make it shorter, so I created virtual directory on server and redirected, result url looks like:

***app.domain.com***

An here comes the problem: the application, which was perfectly working before, started to throw error message "Access is denied.", because it is still searching pages under AppName directory.
So I enter ***app.domain.com*** and it is changed to ***app.domain.com/AppName/default.aspx*** in the browser address line.

I searched source code, project settings, Web.config, but never saw diretory name included.

Could you please help me with that problem? I am already after deadline and unable to find a solution :(.

Thank you in advance,

HoGo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution so made a workaround...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your solution so if other have the same issue, they can find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same application pool in both cases, and that both your old applcation and the new website point to the same folder.